# Asynchronous readline loop without async / await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I'd like to be using this function (which runs fine on my laptop), or something like it, on my embedded device. But two problems:

1. Node.JS on our device is so old that the JavaScript doesn't support async / await. Given our hundreds of units in the field, updating is probably impractical.
2. Even if that weren't a problem, we have another problem: the file may be tens of megabytes in size, not something that could fit in memory all at once.  And this for-await loop will set thousands of asynchronous tasks into motion, more or less all at once.

---

```
async function sendOldData(pathname) {
    const reader = ReadLine.createInterface({
      input: fs.createReadStream(pathname), 
      crlfDelay: Infinity
     })
    for await (const line of reader) {
      record = JSON.parse(line);
      sendOldRecord(record);
    }
}

function sendOldRecord(record) {...}
```

Promises work in this old version. I'm sure there is a graceful syntax for doing this sequentially with Promises:

```
read one line
massage its data
send that data to our server
```

sequentially, but asynchronously, so that the JavaScript event loop is not blocked while the data is sent to the server.

Please, could someone suggest the right syntax for doing this in my outdated JavaScript?

Comment: So do a queue with a promise

Comment: "*Node.JS on our device is so old that the JavaScript doesn't support async / await*" - so just use a transpiler

Comment: "*this for-await loop will set thousands of asynchronous tasks into motion*" - no it doesn't? Or are you saying that `sendOldRecord` is asynchronous? If yes, it should return a promise that you can `await` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Make a queue so it takes the next one off the array

```js
function foo() {

  const reader = [
    '{"foo": 1}',
    '{"foo": 2}',
    '{"foo": 3}',
    '{"foo": 4}',
    '{"foo": 5}',
  ];


  function doNext() {
    if (!reader.length) {
      console.log('done');
      return;
    }
    const line = reader.shift();
    const record = JSON.parse(line);
    sendOldRecord(record, doNext);
  }
  
  doNext();

}

function sendOldRecord(record, done) {
  console.log(record);
  // what ever your async task is
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    done();
  }, Math.floor(2000 * Math.random()));
}

foo();
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, setTimeout is to create a gap so that I'm not holding onto the event loop firmly. But it's waiting for a random time, not waiting until my asynchronous task is done, right? If so, I'm going to try for something more efficient.

Comment: That timeout was to act like an asynchronouse request. I assume that sendOldRecord is doing something asynchronous, it is a guess since you did not show what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can achieve this using functional approach:

```
const arrayOfValues = [1,2,3,4,5];

const chainOfPromises = arrayOfValues.reduce((acc, item) => {

  return acc.then((result) => {
    // Here you can add your logic for parsing/sending request
    
    // And here you are chaining next promise request
    return yourAsyncFunction(item);
  })

}, Promise.resolve());

// Basically this will do
// Promise.resolve().then(_ => yourAsyncFunction(1)).then(_ => yourAsyncFunction(2)) and so on...

// Start
chainOfPromises.then();
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Streams and asynchronous processing are somewhat of a pain to get them to work well together and handle all possible error conditions and things are even worse for the `readline` module.  Since you seem to be saying that you can't use the `for await ()` construct for the readable (which even when it is supported, has various issues), things are even a bit more complicated.

The main problem with `readline.createInterface()` on a stream is that it reads a chunk of the file, parses that chunk for full lines and then synchronously sends all the lines in a tight for loop.

You can literally see the code [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/094b2ae9ba2db28254bb09207a58bd9730ff097d/lib/internal/readline/interface.js#L607):

```
for (let n = 0; n < lines.length; n++) this[kOnLine](lines[n]);
```

The implementation of `kOnLine` does this:

```
 this.emit('line', line);
```

So, this is a tight `for` loop that emits all the lines it read out.  So ... if you try to do something asynchronous in your responding to the `line` event, the moment you hit an `await` or an asynchronous callback, this readline code will send the next `line` event before you're done processing the previous one.  This makes it a pain to do asynchronous processing of the `line` events in sequential order where you finishing asynchronous processing one line before starting on the next one.  IMO, this is a very busted design as it only really works with synchronous processing.  You will notice that this `for` loop also doesn't care if the readline object was paused either.  It just pumps out all the lines it has without regard for anything.

**Discussion of Possible Solutions**

So, what to do about that.  Some part of a fix for this is in the asynchronous iterator interface to readline (but it has other problems which I've filed bugs on).  But, the supposition of your question seems to be that you can't use that asynchronous iterator interface because your device may have an older version of nodejs.  If that's the case, then I only know of two options:

1. Ditch the `readline.createInterface()` functionality entirely and either use a 3rd party module or do your own line boundary processing.
2. Cover the `line` event with your own code that supports asynchronous processing of lines without getting the next line in the middle of still processing the previous one.

**A Solution**

I've written an implementation for option #2, covering the line event with your own code.  In my implementation, we just acknowledge that line events will arrive during our asynchronous processing of previous lines, but instead of notifying you about then, the input stream gets paused and these "early" lines get queued.  With this solution the readline code will read a chunk of data from the input stream, parse it into its full lines, synchronously send all the `line` events for those full lines.  But, upon receipt of the first line event, we will pause the input stream and initiate queueing of subsequent line events.  So, you can asynchronously process a line and you won't get another one until you ask for the next line.

This code has a different way of communicating incoming lines to your code.  Since we're in the age of promises for asynchronous code, I've added a promise-based `reader.getNextLine()` function to the reader object.

This lets you write code like this:

```
import fs from 'fs';

async function run(filename) {
    let reader = createLineReader({
        input: fs.createReadStream(filename),
        crlfDelay: Infinity
    });

    let line;
    let cntr = 0;
    while ((line = await reader.getNextLine()) !== null) {
        // simulate some asynchronous operation in the processing of the line
        console.log(`${++cntr}: ${line}`);
        await processLine(line);
    }
}

run("temp.txt").then(result => {
    console.log("done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

And, here's the implementation of `createLineReader()`:

```
import * as ReadLine from 'readline';

function createLineReader(options) {
    const stream = options.input;
    const reader = ReadLine.createInterface(options);

    // state machine variables
    let latchedErr = null;
    let isPaused = false;
    let readerClosed = false;
    const queuedLines = [];

    // resolves with line
    // resolves with null if no more lines
    // rejects with error
    reader.getNextLine = async function() {
        if (latchedErr) {
            // once we get an error, we're done
            throw latchedErr;
        } else if (queuedLines.length) {
            // if something in the queue, return the oldest from the queue
            const line = queuedLines.shift();
            if (queuedLines.length === 0 && isPaused) {
                reader.resume();
            }
            return line;
        } else if (readerClosed) {
            // if nothing in the queue and the reader is closed, then signify end of data
            return null;
        } else {
            // waiting for more line data to arrive
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                function clear() {
                    reader.off('error', errorListener);
                    reader.off('queued', queuedListener);
                    reader.off('done', doneListener);
                }

                function queuedListener() {
                    clear();
                    resolve(queuedLines.shift());
                }

                function errorListener(e) {
                    clear();
                    reject(e);
                }

                function doneListener() {
                    clear();
                    resolve(null);
                }

                reader.once('queued', queuedListener);
                reader.once('error', errorListener);
                reader.once('done', doneListener);
            });
        }
    }

    reader.on('pause', () => {
        isPaused = true;
    }).on('resume', () => {
        isPaused = false;
    }).on('line', line => {
        queuedLines.push(line);
        if (!isPaused) {
            reader.pause();
        }
        // tell any queue listener that something was just added to the queue
        reader.emit('queued');
    }).on('close', () => {
        readerClosed = true;
        if (queuedLines.length === 0) {
            reader.emit('done');
        }
    });

    return reader;
}
```

**Explanation**

Internally, the implementation takes each new `line` event and puts it into a queue.  Then, `reader.getNextLine()` just pulls items from the queue or waits (with a promise) for the queue to get something put in it.

During operation, the readline object will get a chunk of data from your readstream, it will parse that into whole lines.  The whole lines will all get added to the queue (via `line` events).  The readstream will be paused so it won't generate any more lines until the queue has been drained.

When the queue becomes empty, the readstream will be resumed so it can send more data to the reader object.

This is scalable to very large files because it will only queue the whole lines found in one chunk of the file being read.  Once those lines are queued, the input stream is paused so it won't put more into the queue.  After the queue is drained, the inputs stream is resumed so it can send more data and repeat...

Any errors in the readstream will trigger an error event on the readline object which will either reject a `reader.getNextLine()` that is already waiting for the next line or will reject the next time `reader.getNextLine()` is called.

**Disclaimers**

This has only been tested with file-based readstreams.

I would not recommend having more than one `reader.getNextLine()` in process at once as this code does not anticipate that and it's not even clear what that should do.

Comment: Help me understand how JavaScript works: processLine may call itself asynchronously. There may be thousands of lines in the file. Is this going to result in a call stack thousands of frames deep? If so, I don't like it. Or does the asynchrony somehow prevent that from happening?

Comment: @Joymaker - No stack build-up.  The stack is completely unwound from the previous call inside a `.then()` handler.  This is defined in the promise specification.  The previous call has already returned control back to the event loop and then some new event on a clean stack triggered things.  So, there is no stack build-up when you call itself from within an asynchronous callback.  This is a common technique in Javascript (particularly before you could use `await`).

Comment: @Joymaker - FYI, I found some problems with the code in this answer.  I'm working on fixes.  Boy, do I hate `readline`.  The interface object it creates is not the actual stream so some this code needs to be modified.  Working on it.  And, sure enough the `line` events don't respect pausing until the internal buffer is exhausted.  The readline interface is a total mess.  Solution coming in a bit.

Comment: @Joymaker - I updated this to a completely new implementation that works for me in testing.

Comment: @Joymaker - Any thoughts on this new solution?